# .htaccess : how make URL rewrite for Symfony AND Wordpress at the same time

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, symfony

i have one domain and one server for all my web app, my server already got a wordpress and a php app but i want to add a symfony app on it (i really understand that's not a good way to do it).

But i have troubles with my .htaccess...

My server looks like :

[server_root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIlbL.png)

My wordpress works correctly, myapp1 (full php) works correctly, but myapp2 (Symfony 4) doesn't seems to work.

When i go to www.mydomain.com/myapp2/public i have the good redirection to www.mydomain.com/myapp2/public/login but with a wordpress 404 not found error ...

i'm 100% sure i have to change something in the .htaccess file but i can't figure out how making it work...

i tried to add some lines but nothing seems to work..

here is the .htaccess file of my server :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

i really need help on this ... sorry to bother with my problems,

thanks in advance

Comment: please include the htaccess file in a code block instead of an image, this makes it instantly visible, copy pastable (so someone can test if he wants to) and it wont get deleted by some external site removing the context for people ending up here later on. Also you can show the image in the question instead of having it as a link.

Comment: I edited, seems like i need more reputation for displaying image tho,

thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jenne said your current .htaccess for your Wordpress application does rewrite everything which is not

- an existing directory
- an existing file

to the *index.php* of Wordpress.

That is why your PHP application has worked fine. Symfony however needs a rewrite of everyting to its *index.php* too.

I do **not** recommend locating Symfony inside a public directory. As Jenne said you **should** locate it outside of it and e.g. create a own subdomain which root directory is the public directory of your Symfony application.

But you can add an extra rewrite rule to your *.htaccess* file which does the needed rewriting for Symfony.

```
# If the path points inside the myapp2 public folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myapp2/public/.
# and there is a file at that path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
# use that file.
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the url points to /myapp2 use the Symfony index.php.
RewriteRule ^/myapp2(/.*)?$ /myapp2/public/index.php [L]

# If the path points to something which is no existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# use the Wordpress index.php.
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

That way you can access all files in the Symfony public directory like that:
`www.example.com/myapp2/public/somefile.txt`

And use everything else at `/myapp2` for your Symfony routes. But all files which are in your *myapp2* folder and outside of the *public* folder can't be accessed.

Comment: It seems to WORK !! Just needed time to the server to accept change from the .htaccess file. Have some errors, but this time with the Symfony error handler so i'll check myself, thanks a lot to you and Jenne for the advice !

Answer (score 0):

**Lets do a warning first: having all these files in those public folders like this is very BAD as we can simply open the configuration files browsing to eg `yourhost/myapp1/config/services.yaml`. And these will be fully readable! It is therefor advised to only expose the public folder of symfony projects (the one that has the index.php) to the outside world. Or you would have to edit the htaccess even further to only allow acces to specific file types/folders like assets**

There is an answer to the question though, what is going on is:

```
# If the requested path is NOT (!) an actual file (-f) on the disk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# And if the requested path is NOT (!) an actual directory (-d) on the disk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite any path (`.` is a regex where the dot will match anything) to /index.php
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

There for calling file/directory in myapp1/2 would work as they are actual file calls and wont get forwarded to the root/index.php (wordpress).

We can solve this by adding

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myapp1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myapp2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

The first two can also combined in regex using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(myapp1|myapp2)`

This results in any path:

- NOT starting with /myapp1
- AND NOT starting with /myapp2
- AND IS NOT a file
- AND IS NOT a directory

being rewritten to `/index.php`.

You can then also add a .htaccess in myapp1/2 to do the rewriting for those apps specifically.

Comment: I tried to add those line to the main .htaccess but it blocked the wordpress css file :/ and didn't resolve my problem, 

then i tried to add a .htaccess file to myapp2 root but it doesn't seem to work.

if i understood i change:
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L] BY

 RewriteRule . /public/index.php [L]


to the .htaccess right?

Comment: Just tested this and it did work as expected. I did miss the `RewriteEngine on` though, so maybe it wasn't active in your test? But I can access a static file like `/assets/bleep.txt`.

Comment: Its works now, dunno there is a HUGE delay before my server accept changes, thanks for your help